# Do we "study about" something?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, dialects

I accept **study about** where study is a noun ("He conducted a study about changes in population"), but I saw this construct in a local newspaper article and it struck me as odd. Here, **study** is a verb. Is this actually acceptable or is it just a regional variation that has mistakenly made its way into print?

> More than 30 seventh- and eighth-graders and their chaperones will be
> flying to Washington, D.C., for a five-day trip to see the
> places and monuments they have been **studying about** this year.
>
> The students have been **studying about** the U.S. government.

Comment: The standard idiom that turns up in a Google search is "This was a study about X" and "about" can be replaced with "on" or "of". I think that this is a misusage because while I _think about_, _read about_, and _hear about_ X, I _study X_. But it may be a localism or a regionalism. Certainly, a good editor would have deleted "about" in that sentence.

Comment: I think you need to study the dictionary's [full definition](http://www.onelook.com/?w=study&ls=a) more carefully.

Comment: `study about`, `discuss about`, etc. is often a South Asian English (especially Indian English) regionalism. Note that there *are* a few valid uses of `study about` outside of Indian English, but Indian English speakers often use `study about` even when the `about` is not required or needed.

Answer (score 7):

With domains and other abstract areas, *study* used transitively rather than with a prepositional phrase (or what looks like one) is adequate and I would say to be preferred:

He is studying physics / medicine / history / the history of magic / the situation carefully / ...

However, there can be a distinct difference in meaning when an object that may be concrete is involved:

He was studying Rembrandt's paintings in the Springvale Art Gallery.

He was studying about Rembrandt's paintings in books he had borrowed from the library.

The difference is far clearer with:

She read Chaucer whenever she had any free time.

She read about Chaucer whenever she had any free time.

Comment: I agree that **read/read about** are different, but I'm not sure I agree for **study**. Even if I were only looking at a copy of a Picaso painting online or reading an article about the meaning behind the painting, I would use **studying**. Doesn't study already imply that I'm accessing all kinds of related information in addition to the original (if any)?

Comment: @user113215  I agree with both you and Edwin. In an academic context I would tend to use *study* by itself and take the consultation of secondary or ancillary matter for granted; but in a 'school' context it might be valuable to distinguish *study* from *study about*: for instance, I would not want parents to think that their teenagers were studying sexually transmitted diseases at first hand!

Comment: Just because *read Chaucer* and *read about Chaucer* can convey different meanings doesn't imply a similar distinction can be made with *study*. It's just that we don't *usually* use a preposition after *study*, but it's [certainly not that uncommon.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22studied+about+the%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: *Read about* being correct does not make *study about* correct. We can study paintings, or *learn about* the painters, but we don't *study about* the painters. Study means to examine or scrutinise an object - study a face - but the verb for gaining knowledge is *learn*. We study a book to learn about painters.

Answer (score 3):

Your final paragraph seems to betray a misunderstanding about objects. In your text, *studying* does not have an object: *about* is not the object of the verb. Neither is it a preposition in the first place where it appears. It modifies *studying*. In this context, *about* might best be described as an adverb.

The usage is awkward because *study* does not typically get paired with *about* as a modifier. A better word in its place would be *learning*, because *learn* is commonly used with *about*.

Comment: Why has this answer got two down votes, when what he says is completely correct? +1 from me to offset the political voting.

Comment: Maybe retaliatory voting. I've suddenly had three downvotes in the last hour, one on an answer I posted almost a year ago. Not worth fretting about.

Comment: Didn't Churchill say: "Oh yes, democracy is the worst possible form of government.

Apart from all the others"?

Comment: On the other hand, I had to read your answer three times before I figured out what you were saying and that you were correct. Maybe the downvoters only read it once. For example, *"neither is it a preposition in the first place where it appears"*  could be phrased more comprehensibly.

Comment: Edit welcome. It seems plain to me but I never mind getting schooled.

Answer (score 0):

">OED says "To apply the mind to the acquisition of learning, whether by means of books, observation, or experiment. †Const. in, on, upon (a book, a branch of learning). See also sense 1d."

1d is "To make a close study of (a subject), to ‘bone’ up (on, in), esp. in preparation for some display of knowledge (intr. use of sense 7b). U.S. colloq.

1946   Chicago Daily News 25 June 31/3   Ah'll git a li'l closer, an' study up on him!
1956   R. Robinson Landscape with Dead Dons xiii. 114,   I am sure that if you once studied up a little in psychology you would be as struck as I was."

It also mentions a second sense of 'meditation':" To think intently; to meditate (about, †of, on, upon, in); to reflect, try to recollect something or to come to a decision. Now dial. and U.S. colloq."

This does allow a 'about', but is non-standard; a US colloquialism or dialect.